# Can not install Orchard CMS 1.6 on Godaddy Web Hosting

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

After reading on the web that Orchard CMS can be installed on shared hosting, I tried to install Orchard CMS 1.6 on Godaddy Web Hosting with MySQL database. I performed following steps -

- Verified that my root directory is set to Integrated pipeline mode.
- Downloaded the ZIP Package from Codeplex and uploaded to my root directory on my hosting account
- In Godaddy file manager set write permissions to following folders (App_Data, Config, Themes, Media, Modules)
- Also created a MYSQL database

When I accessed the Orchard **first time** I got Internal server error, to see the error message I modified the Web.config and got a long error message as give below

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:
[TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.]
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy..ctor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) +0
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy..ctor() +22

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(String repositoryName, Type repositoryType) +509
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly, Type repositoryType, String repositoryName, Boolean readAssemblyAttributes) +457
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly, Type repositoryType) +17
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.GetRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly) +42
log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name) +55
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name) +8
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(String name) +20
Orchard.Logging.OrchardLog4netFactory.Create(String name) in OrchardLog4netFactory.cs:28
Castle.Core.Logging.AbstractLoggerFactory.Create(Type type) +31
Orchard.Logging.CastleLoggerFactory.CreateLogger(Type type) in CastleLoggerFactory.cs:12
Orchard.Logging.LoggingModule.CreateLogger(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in LoggingModule.cs:75
Autofac.Builder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +17
Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +30
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +48
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +48
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +167
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +23
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +72
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +54
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +121
Orchard.Logging.<>c__DisplayClass11.<BuildLoggerInjectors>b__8(String key) in LoggingModule.cs:65
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
Orchard.Logging.<>c__DisplayClassf.<BuildLoggerInjectors>b__7(IComponentContext ctx, Object instance) in LoggingModule.cs:65
Orchard.Logging.<>c__DisplayClass1.<AttachToComponentRegistration>b__0(Object s, ActivatedEventArgs`1 e) in LoggingModule.cs:40
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.RaiseActivated(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object instance) +70
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Complete() +85
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.CompleteActivations() +114
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +207
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +50

[DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details.]
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +119
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +159
Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +17
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +72
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +54
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +121
Orchard.Environment.OrchardStarter.CreateHostContainer(Action`1 registrations) in OrchardStarter.cs:132
Orchard.Web.MvcApplication.HostInitialization(HttpApplication application) in Global.asax.cs:46
Orchard.WarmupStarter.<>c__DisplayClass3.<LaunchStartupThread>b__2(Object state) in Starter.cs:89

[ApplicationException: Error during application initialization]
Orchard.WarmupStarter.Starter`1.OnBeginRequest(HttpApplication application) in Starter.cs:63
Orchard.Web.MvcApplication.Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax.cs:29

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +335
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
System.Web.Util.ArglessEventHandlerProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +57
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Has anyone seen this error before, I am competently new to Orchard and ASP.NET MVC

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy apparently does not give you full trust, which is required. There is no good reason today for a hoster not to grant full trust. You should try to find a good hosting company instead.

Update: GoDaddy now provides full trust, and it is possible to run Orchard there. I personally prefer not to, for many reasons, but that's probably a little off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, I will cancel my Hosting at Godaddy and find another Hosting with full trust.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is correct. GoDaddy allows you to set <trust level="Full" /> under <system.web>. I've deployed many Orchard sites on GoDaddy, and they run fine! :)

Comment: It used to be. Now, they do give full trust, yes.

Answer (score 0):

in order to host orchid cms on godaddy you need read/write/delete permissions on assemblies which is not allowed under shared hosting. you need full access and full trust like roy said you have to have dedicated hosting or shared hosting with full trust.

thanks